# Where is the documentation of Honeycomb's new widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm looking to create some widgets for Honeycomb, and I've successfully created a [`StackView` widget](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/src/com/example/android/stackwidget/index.html) for my application, but I'd like to add some others of the new widgets in Honeycomb.

[image: Image from Android developer site]

I'm especially looking for documentation on the widget to the right in the above image, but so far haven't been able to find anything on the Android developer site nor by searching on Google. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html). You can probably just replace `StackView` with `GridView` in your layout and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation on honeycomb,

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html

you can also find all api levels here,

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Comment: Not really helpful. I'm looking for something specific, not Honeycomb in general. Besides, a lot of the stuff in Honeycomb is not yet documented.